# perform a where in query in bookshelf.js

Tags: bookshelf.js

I want to perform a `WHERE - IN` query/operation but normal where gives error.

I want this

```
select * from `calendar_event_rsvp` where `event_id` in ('1', '2', '3')
```

But below code leads to

```
select * from `calendar_event_rsvp` where `event_id in` = '1', '2', '3'
```

**Code**

```
CalendarEventRSVP.forge()
                .where({
                    "event_id": event_ids
                })
```

How do i do this in bookshelf.js

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to add the operator:

```
CalendarEventRSVP.forge()
            .where('event_id', 'in', event_ids)
```

Or use knex's `whereIn`:

```
 CalendarEventRSVP.forge()
            .query({whereIn: {event_id: event_ids}})
```

Comment: I'm afraid not, I don't have any real experience with bookshelf

Comment: I have fiddled in my spare time with Knex, which is what bookshelf uses

Answer (score 6):

try **query()** function on your model.

```
CalendarEventRSVP.query(function(qb){
    qb.where('event_id' , 'in' , [1,2,3,4]) ;
})
.fetchAll()
.then();
```