# How do I use both a '<>' and a 'whereNotIn' when querying with knex and Bookshelf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have a model, 'Excerpt', and want to fetch all excerpts that are NOT owned by a given user, and are NOT in a list of excluded excerpts *(e.g. no excerpts with id's from the list [0, 1, 2, 3])*.

I've successfully selected all excerpts not owned by a user, by using:

```
Excerpt
    .query({
        whereNot: { owner_id : req.currentUser.id }
    })
    .fetchAll()
    .then((excerptResults) => {
      res.status(200).json(excerptResults);
    });
```

and I have tried to use `whereNotIn` to exclude excerpts with the following snippet *(as per [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131004/perform-a-where-in-query-in-bookshelf-js))*:

```
Excerpt
    .query({
      whereNotIn: { id : [0, 1, 2, 3] }
    })
    .fetchAll()
    .then((excerptResults) => {
      var tasks = [];
      for(var i=0; i<excerptResults.models.length; i++) {
        tasks.push(excerptResults.models[i].attributes);
      }
      res.status(200).json(tasks);
    });
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message

`Unhandled rejection Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query: select "excerpts".* from "excerpts" where "[object Object]" not in (?)`

I don't really understand the error message. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Try `Excerpt.whereNotIn('id', [0, 1, 2, 3])`

Comment: @MukeshSharma I just get the error `Unhandled rejection TypeError: _excerpts2.default.whereNotIn is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should for your case :

```
Excerpt.query(function(qb){
   qb.where('id','not in', [0,1,2,3]).andWhere('owner_id','=',req.currentUser.id )
})
.fetchAll()
.then(...);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. How would I chain it with my original `whereNot` query to  exclude excerpts owned by the user? I'm unfamiliar with this syntax.